# How to return a list of table in database?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

Write a function named "get_records" that doesn't take any parameters. There is a database saved in a file named "apologize.db" containing a table named "foreigner" with columns "confirm", "handful", and "chemistry". Return a list containing all the records in the table "foreigner".

```
import sqlite3
def get_records():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("apologize.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO foreigner VALUES (
                    "confirm",
                    "handful",
                    "chemistry")')
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what your question says, I believe that you are looking for something similar to the following.

```
def get_records():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("apologize.db")
    conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
    c = conn.cursor()
    confirm_list = c.execute('SELECT confirm FROM foreigner').fetchall()
    handful_list = c.execute('SELECT handful FROM foreigner').fetchall()
    chemistry_list = c.execute('SELECT chemistry FROM foreigner').fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return [confirm_list, handful_list, chemistry_list]
```

Or

```
def get_records():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("apologize.db")
    conn.row_factory = lambda cursor, row: row[0]
    c = conn.cursor()
    confirm_list = c.execute('SELECT confirm FROM foreigner').fetchall()
    handful_list = c.execute('SELECT handful FROM foreigner').fetchall()
    chemistry_list = c.execute('SELECT chemistry FROM foreigner').fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return [list(x) for x in zip(confirm_list, handful_list, chemistry_list)]
```

Cheers!

Comment: I am getting function get_records incorrect on input []

returned: [['shall', 'walking', 'poem', 'square', 'frustrate', 'soft'], ['tragic', 'brake', 'night', 'push', 'flood', 'information'], ['craft', 'heat', 'deal', 'productivity', 'neighbor', 'patent']]
                                                                                                       expected: [['shall', 'tragic', 'craft'], ['walking', 'brake', 'heat'], ['poem', 'night', 'deal'], ['square', 'push', 'productivity'], ['frustrate', 'flood', 'neighbor'], ['soft', 'information', 'patent']]

Comment: Ok, it is looking for a row traversal I'll edit my solution in a second.

Comment: Why in the world are you using three different queries for getting values from the table?

Comment: @Shawn Originally I figured that Anonymous wanted each column separately. Therefore, I figured that the simplest way using the row factor would be sol 1. Given that Anonymous actually wanted rows, it just added the zip, because it was the simplest transition from what I already had, not the most efficient.

Comment: expected: [['shall', 'tragic', 'craft'], ['walking', 'brake', 'heat'], ['poem', 'night', 'deal'], ['square', 'push', 'productivity'], ['frustrate', 'flood', 'neighbor'], ['soft', 'information', 'patent']]

Comment: Yours returned returned: [[['shall'], ['walking'], ['poem'], ['square'], ['frustrate'], ['soft']], [['tragic'], ['brake'], ['night'], ['push'], ['flood'], ['information']], [['craft'], ['heat'], ['deal'], ['productivity'], ['neighbor'], ['patent']]]

Comment: @Anonymous Should be actually fixed this time.

Comment: May I ask why lambda?

Comment: If you call it without it it will return values like this [(u'shall',), (u'walking',), (u'poem',), ...]

Comment: And what about the 'zip'?

Answer (score 1):

You are using INSERT start with not SELECT start there...
Review your code after that see where to go nex

Answer (score 0):

Instead of spending a few hours learning how to solve this specific problem with SQL, I suggest you signs a few hours learning [an ORM like sqlalchemy](https://www.pythoncentral.io/introductory-tutorial-python-sqlalchemy/) and never have to write SQL ever again.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Foreigner(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foreigner'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    confirm = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    handful = ...
    chemistry = ...

records = Foreigner.query.all()
```

Comment: How would you attempt the problem using sql? The compiler that I am using in University doesn't support sqlalchemy.

Comment: There are other answers for how to solve using SQL, so I'll not retreat their ground. Instead I suggest determine how to install sqlalchemy on your machine. Are you unable to `pip install sqlalchemy`?